# Beautifulsoup script tag extract data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, tags

Trying to extract values, from the script tag but get no output.  Unsure what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
detail_url 
address 
beds 
baths 
price
```

Code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

def extract_property_info(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    script_tag = soup.find('script', {'type': 'application/json', 'ss-data-keyy': 'mobileSearchPageStore'})

    if script_tag:
        script_content = script_tag.contents[0]
        try:
            json_data = BeautifulSoup(script_content, 'html.parser').string.strip()
            data = json.loads(json_data)
            
            # Extract the desired values
            detail_url = data['detailUrl']
            address = data['address']
            beds = data['beds']
            baths = data['baths']
            price = data['price']
            
            # Return the extracted values
            return detail_url, address, beds, baths, price
        except (AttributeError, json.JSONDecodeError):
            pass

    return None

# HTML content 
html_content = '''
<html>
<body>
    <script type="application/json" ss-data-keyy="mobileSearchPageStore">
    <!--{"queryState":numberFormatter":"0,0","inputFormatter":"0.[0]a"}},"sortOrder":1,"type":"Range","defaultValue":{"min":null,"max":null},"suggestedEnums":500","value":500},{"url":"https://photos.example.com/fp/e0ba89ff3ebcb9d689dcf6d0ffd87868-p_e.jpg"}],"detailUrl":"https://www.example.com/homedetails/111-S-1316th-St-Arizona-AZ-3324332/33327367_ppid/","statusType":"FOR_SALE","statusText":"home for buy","countryCurrency":"$","price":"$269,000","unformattedPrice":269000,"address":"111 S 1316th St Arizona AZ 33243322","addressStreet":"111 S 1316th St","addressCity":"Arizona","addressState":"OH","addressZipcode":"33243322","isUndisclosedAddress":false,"beds":4,"baths":2.0,"area":2467,"latLong":{"latitude":12.12345,"longitude":12.12345},"isexampleOwned":false,"variableData":{"type":"DAYS_ON","text":"2 days on example"},"badgeInfo":null,}],}-->
    </script>
</body>
</html>
'''

# Call the function and print the extracted values
result = extract_property_info(html_content)
print("Result: " , result)
if result is not None:
    detail_url, address, beds, baths, price = result
    print("Detail URL:", detail_url)
    print("Address:", address)
    print("Beds:", beds)
    print("Baths:", baths)
    print("Price:", price)
else:
    print("Unable to extract property information.")
```

Comment: JSON kind of comment is not correct. Hence json.loads return None. If possible correct the JSON content within HTML comment section (or) try to parse the string by yourself using regex

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because JSON in HTML is not correct. So it is throwing an Exception while converting string to dict but you have mentioned `pass` in exception so you did not catch up the same.
I have tried with some default value in JSON : `{"detailUrl":"detailUrl", "address": "address","beds": "Beds", "baths":"baths", "price":"price"}`

Complete code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

def extract_property_info(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    script_tag = soup.find('script', {'type': 'application/json', 'ss-data-keyy': 'mobileSearchPageStore'})

    if script_tag:
        script_content = script_tag.contents[0]
        try:
            json_data = BeautifulSoup(script_content, 'html.parser').string.strip()
            data = json.loads(json_data)
            
            # Extract the desired values
            detail_url = data['detailUrl']
            address = data['address']
            beds = data['beds']
            baths = data['baths']
            price = data['price']
            
            # Return the extracted values
            return detail_url, address, beds, baths, price
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)

    return None

# HTML content 
html_content = '''
<html>
<body>
    <script type="application/json" ss-data-keyy="mobileSearchPageStore">
    {"detailUrl":"detailUrl", "address": "address","beds": "Beds", "baths":"baths", "price":"price"}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
'''

# Call the function and print the extracted values
result = extract_property_info(html_content)
print("Result: " , result)
if result is not None:
    detail_url, address, beds, baths, price = result
    print("Detail URL:", detail_url)
    print("Address:", address)
    print("Beds:", beds)
    print("Baths:", baths)
    print("Price:", price)
else:
    print("Unable to extract property information.")
```

**Output**:

```
Result:  ('detailUrl', 'address', 'Beds', 'baths', 'price')
Detail URL: detailUrl
Address: address
Beds: Beds
Baths: baths
Price: price
```